# Fatal Exception Debuging & Learning

Tags: java, android, xml

So I tried to make a port scanner and I got stuck on the way and i will love to get some explication of what am I doing wrong here(and almost every time) when I am starting a new activity.

P.S. :4rd time programing with java in my life.

My java:

```
package com.nliplace.nli.xxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class portscan extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Portaa  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText Portbb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText Iptot = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    TextView rez = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portscan);

    }
    private static String available(String ip, int porta, int portb) {
        String rezultat = "";
        for (int port = porta; port <= portb; port++) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("185.28.20.123", port), 1000);
                socket.close();
                rezultat = rezultat + "," + port;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }
        return rezultat;
    }

    public void scanclick(View s) {
        // Scaneaza
        Iptot= (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Portaa = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Portbb = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        String portaa = Portaa.getText().toString();
        int porta = Integer.parseInt(portaa);
        String portbb = Portbb.getText().toString();
        int portb = Integer.parseInt(portbb);
        String ip = Iptot.getText().toString();
        // available(ip, porta, portb);
        //textView18
        rez.setText(available(ip, porta, portb));
    }


}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nliplace.nli.unealta.portscan">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Aceasta activitate scaneaza dupa port-uri deschise."
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Adresa:"
            android:id="@+id/textView14" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Port A:"
            android:id="@+id/textView15" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Port B:"
            android:id="@+id/textView16" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="scanclick" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Aici se vor afisa porturile deschise:"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="...va dura..."
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My challenge for you guys:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.nliplace.nli.unealta, PID: 20048
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.nliplace.nli.unealta/com.nliplace.nli.unealta.portscan}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2172)
>                                                                                 at com.nliplace.nli.unealta.portscan.(portscan.java:20)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Comment: very rude of you :) I want tips! no need to write all the code!

Comment: and I just need someone to say/scream at me at what am I doing wrong.

Comment: oh ..s... now i see :))

Comment: thank you for the explication :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `findViewById()` method before using `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. Put find views inside onCreate() after setContentView() method like this:

```
public class portscan extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Portaa;
    EditText Portbb;
    EditText Iptot;
    TextView rez;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portscan);
     Portaa  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Portbb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Iptot = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    rez = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);

    }...
```

You were basically trying to find something that doesnt exist.

Comment: Thank you i fixed it also with:

 EditText Portaa;
 EditText Portbb;
 EditText Iptot;
 TextView rez;

.....

rez = new TextView(this);
        rez = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        rez.setText(available(ip, porta, portb)); Any difference?

Comment: you dont have to use `rez = new TextView(this);` **rez** is already a **TextView type**. After this fix any more errors?

Comment: it's jut not working :)) what about  private static String available?

Comment: Well the errors you posted before were about invoking `findViewById()` so what are the errors now? sayind "its just not working" doesnt give a clue. Btw. since your views are global you dont need to use `findViewById()` every time you wanna use them, just once in onCreate. Say what are the problems now, and I will check when I wake up.

Comment: Ok let me try to see why "private static String available" it's not working. I want to smash my head until I figure it out. Anyway you answered to my questions. :)